# Android: animation bug

Tags: android

I have that strange bug that I cannot figure out why. When I start the application it just moves 100 pixels down. But when I touch on the frameLayout it moves relativeLayout.getHeight()+100. I guess its because the application couldnt get the relativeLayout's height. What do you think?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageView imageViewEater, imageViewFaller;
private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
private FrameLayout frameLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageViewEater = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.eater);
    relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
    frameLayout = (FrameLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);

    imageViewFaller = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.faller);
    imageViewFaller.setY(0);

    frameLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            //Move to the touched position
            float x = event.getX() - imageViewEater.getWidth() / 2;
            imageViewEater.animate().translationX(x).setDuration(200).start();
            fallDown();
            return false;
        }
    });

    fallDown();
}

private void fallDown() {
    imageViewFaller.setY(0);
    imageViewFaller.setX(new Random().nextInt(800 - 100));
    imageViewFaller.animate().translationY(relativeLayout.getHeight()+100).setDuration(1000).start();
}
```

}

**UPDATE**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">


<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300px"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/eater"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/eater" />
</FrameLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/faller"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@drawable/faller" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: please insert xml code to detect your problem.

Comment: I added the XML. Thanks.

Comment: You have 300px height FrameLayout and the inside, you have 150 dp height Imageview. Where is the logic of that?. On a xxhdpi device 150dp equals 450px. Do rest of the calculations yourself.

Comment: @oguzhand thx for the reminder. But the Problem is still not solved.

Comment: So where is you complete layout?

Comment: You should get RelativeLayout's height by other way.Or just use new Handler().postDelay(new Runnable(),300) to wait relativeLayout to init.

Comment: Great Idea! Can you please post the code? I tryed it but didnt get it...

Answer (score 1):

> This is not good code because when you  touch the framelayout Always
>   check onTouch method.

You can change code like this:

in MainActivity:

```
    import java.util.Random;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.FrameLayout;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageView imageViewEater, imageViewFaller;
    private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    private FrameLayout frameLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageViewEater = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.eater);
        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
        frameLayout = (FrameLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);

        imageViewFaller = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.faller);
        imageViewFaller.setY(0);

       frameLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                //Move to the touched position

                float x = event.getX() - imageViewEater.getWidth() / 2;
               if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){  imageViewEater.animate().translationX(x).setDuration(200).start();
                fallDown();
}
                return true;
            }
        });

        fallDown();
    }

    private void fallDown() {
        imageViewFaller.setY(0);
        imageViewFaller.setX(new Random().nextInt(800 - 100));
        imageViewFaller.animate().translationY(relativeLayout.getMeasuredHeight()+100).setDuration(1000).start();
    }
    }
```

> ***Important***: When you want to use getheight() for relativelayout or
>   framelayout or linearlayout ... . you should call getMeasuredHeigh()
>   to get currectly height

---

> ***Important*** :when you call falldown() in oncreate() method. because
>   relative layout dose not make yet.so relativelayout height is 0.

---

**Quastion**: How i Can detect when create all layout in oncreate() method?

To resolve this issue change MainActivity again;

```
import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageView imageViewEater, imageViewFaller;
    private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    private FrameLayout frameLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageViewEater = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.eater);
        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) this
                .findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
        frameLayout = (FrameLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);

        imageViewFaller = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.faller);
        imageViewFaller.setY(0);

        frameLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // Move to the touched position

                float x = event.getX() - imageViewEater.getWidth() / 2;
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    imageViewEater.animate().translationX(x).setDuration(200)
                            .start();
                    fallDown();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        fallDown();
    }

    private void fallDown() {
        imageViewFaller.setY(0);
        imageViewFaller.setX(new Random().nextInt(800 - 100));
        imageViewFaller.animate()
                .translationY(relativeLayout.getMeasuredHeight() + 100)
                .setDuration(1000).start();
    }
}
```

> **onWindowFocusChanged** called when an action mode is being started for this window. Gives the callback an opportunity to handle the
>   action mode in its own unique and beautiful way.

Comment: Thank you very much! How do you mean relativeLayouts height is 0?